# How to support long running cloudkit sync

Tags: ios, swift, background, cloudkit

I am trying to implement a cloudkit sync. I receive the remote notifcation about changed data via

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)
        print (notification)

        let bgid = application.beginBackgroundTask {
            print ("backgroundtaskhandler called")
        }
        print (application.backgroundTimeRemaining)

        CKManager.ckmanager.handleNotification(bgid: bgid) { (id) in
            application.endBackgroundTask(id)
            completionHandler(.newData)
        }
}
```

As I understand the

`CKManager.ckmanager.handleNotification()`

in the above code has only about 30 seconds to execute before I have to call the completion handler else the app will terminate.

Now I expect the fetching and processing of new records sometimes to take longer than the allowed time. I am not sure how to process this.

If this were an update operation on CKRecords I could use the `isLongLived`flag of the operation but I cannot see how this would work with a fetch operation.

Whithin the ´´´handleNotification´´´ function I call a delegate to process record changes (writing it to a local SQL database):

```
let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: [zoneID!], optionsByRecordZoneID: optionsMap)
operation.fetchAllChanges = true

operation.recordChangedBlock =
{ record in
    self.delegate?.cloudKitRecordChanged(record: record
}
```

Can anyone set me on the right path ?

Comment: You need to call `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` before calling `handleNotification` and call `endBackgroundTask` and `completionHandler(.newData)` in a completion handler from `handleNotification`

Comment: Ok, but then I still have only limited time. Remaining background time was shown as 32.xxx seconds and the app might be terminated after this while the FetchRecord operation is still in progress. How can I make sure, that the operation continues on next oportunity, e.g. when the user brings the app to foreground.

Comment: If you use begin background task then you get up to 180 seconds. In the expiration handler code (that you provide) you would need to gracefully cancel the fetch and track the last update you have received so that you can resume next time you are in the foreground.

Comment: I edited my code above to the current state. When I run this I notice that after about 30 seconds (I am arbitrary delaying the handleNotification with a sleep) the expiration handler is called twice. But the processing still continues. This is on real device with xcode attached. Could it be possible that executing a cloudkit operation superseeds the normalg bg mechanism ?

Comment: Part of the problem here is that your code is not how you write a background task. It's pointless to test until you've written the background task correctly. Plus, ending the background task before calling the completion handler is rather odd, isn't it? You're cutting off your own oxygen.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what I did wrong ? The closure fin the  handle Notification call will be called only after the operation is complete, of course.